# Put all occurences in the String in quotes using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I hava a long string were I can find something like this `data() { <some data which is always different here> }` I want to put all occurences in quotes. This is what I'm doing but it has no effect:

```
string = re.sub(r'data \(\) {(.*)}', r'"/1"', string)
```

I suppose there should be something different between curly brackets but I have no idea what...

**@EDIT**
I realized my String look like this:

```
data() {
  <some white spaces> here is text
<some white spaces> }
```

Comment: `string = re.sub(r'data\(\)\s*{(.*)}', r'"\1"', string)`. Backreferences are defined with a *backslash*, and the spaces are meaningful inside a regex pattern. However, you will not be able to use this in real life where the number of nested `{...}` can be arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitespace matters, the direction of slashes matters (thanks Wiktor, I overlooked that before) and that quantifier should probably be lazy. Also, if there are newlines within your text, you need to allow for that

```
string = re.sub(r'(?s)data\(\) {(.*?)}', r'"\1"', string)
```

Testing it on your sample text:

```
In [4]: string = """data() {
   ...:   <some white spaces> here is text
   ...: <some white spaces> }"""

In [5]: print(re.sub(r'(?s)data\(\) {(.*?)}', r'"\1"', string))
"
  <some white spaces> here is text
<some white spaces> "
```

Comment: Neither `{(.*?)}` nor `{(.*)}` will work in real life where the number of nested `{...}` can be arbitrary.

Comment: yeah, i did the exact thing

Comment: it removed "data" word

Comment: no no no, I want to have something like this: `"data() { some txt }"` not `" some text" `

Comment: Then you need to use `\0` instead of `\1` in the replacement string. `\1` contains what was matched by group `(.*?)`, `\0` contains the entire match.

Comment: I put `string = re.sub(r'(?s)data \(\) {(.*?)}', r"'data () {\1}'", string)` and it works, it is better to use `\0` then?

Comment: oh, when I put `\0` i got a square :P

Comment: Ah, sorry. Edge case. Use `\g<0>`.